# Factorize $X^p+1$ in a field of characteristic $p$.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How can I factorize $X^p+1$ in a field of characteristic $p$ ?

If the field is $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, then $$X^p+1=X^p+1^p=(X+1)^p,$$
but if the field is $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ or if the characteristic is $q\neq p$, I don't know how to do it.

---

It's not duplicate, but it solve my problem for $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. But what happen for a field of characteristic $q\neq p$ ?

Comment: It's still true for a general field of characteristic $p$ that $(X + 1)^p = X^p + 1$.

Comment: Nothing happens at all in general if $p \neq q$. The left hand side might even be irreducible in this case, so you can't find such a nice factorization in general.

Comment: Factorizing $X^p+1$ in a field of characteristic $q \neq p$ depends on both $q$ and the actual field..I mean you can always take $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$ and then it factors into distinct linear factors...

Comment: If you want to consider char $p$, it is a duplicate, if you want to consider char $\neq p$ it is unclear what you are asking. Pick your poison, this gets closed anyway.